# how to extract particular string from a sentence in java

Tags: java, string, split

Am reading a text file line by line and trying to extract a particular string but unable to do so. My file contents would be in the below format

```
CgIn,f,CgIn.util:srv2,1,11.65,42,42,42,42,04,04,04,04
wPub,j,pub.stg:cc,2,100,06,00,12,12,00,12,12,06
wPub,j,pub.f:Log,1,100,08,08,08,08,08,08,08,08
wPub,j,pub.math:add,1,100,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16
wMon,j,admin:img,111,100,04,00,.450,.503,00,.450,.503,04
```

I want to extract this particular string in the format below

```
CgIn,f,CgIn.util:srv2
wPub,j,pub.stg:cc
wPub,j,pub.f:Log
wPub,j,pub.math:add
wMon,j,admin:img
```

Tried using split & substring but my results are not as expected. Please help.

Comment: `xxxx,x,xxx.xxx:xxx,1,2,3,4...` would be the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the same structure in the whole text file (i.e something like: `STRING,STRING,STRING,NUMBERS`), you could do something like the following:

```
String str = "CgIn,f,CgIn.util:srv2,1,11.65,42,42,42,42,04,04,04,04";

String[] s=str.split(",");
System.out.println(s[0]+","+s[1]+","+s[2]);
```

This returns `CgIn,f,CgIn.util:srv2` as output. You can loop over the whole text file and obtain the corresponding result for each string.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can, of course, use split, but it's faster to just match the first three comma-separated strings using a regular expression, especially if the number list is large, and you want to avoid array creation for every line:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^((?:[^,]+,){2}(?:[^,]+)).+$");
String line = "CgIn,f,CgIn.util:srv2,1,11.65,42,42,42,42,04,04,04,04";
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
String result;
if (m.matches()) {
    result = m.group(1);
}
```